# Union and Intersection types order of operations?

Tags: typescript

I have a type scenario where I want to say:

```js
export interface ItemSchema {
  [attrName: string]:
    { type: 'number', default?: number, readOnly?: boolean} |
    { type: 'string', default?: string, readOnly?: boolean} |
    { type: 'boolean', default?: boolean, readOnly?: boolean} |
    { type: 'date', default?: Date, readOnly?: boolean} |
    { type: 'object', default?: object, readOnly?: boolean}
}
```

(because I'm defining a schema that's available at run-time for data getting passed around in JSON format, fwiw, and this is the Interface for the schema).

This is handy, because in my actual type definitions can have `{ type: 'number', default: 2 }` but not `{ type: 'number', default: 'potato' }`.

I'd like to pull the readOnly bit out (and other stuff omitted here for simplicity) into a separate segment. I actually *can* prepend the above stack with `{ readOnly?: boolean } &` and it seems to work, but that depends on some order of operations of these | and & operators that isn't well-documented (at least not in a place I can find).

(parenthetically, I can also use parentheses, it seems, like `{} & ({} | {} | {})`, but that makes my linter freak out, so I'm not sure if parentheses are are officially supported here or if it's just an accident).

So, is there a place where order of operations is defined for these interface composition operators? I don't want to write code that only runs due to an undocumented quirk in the compiler and have it break in 2.3 or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interfaces.

One interface for the base schema:

```
interface Schema { readOnly?: boolean };
```

And then the others who extend it:

```
interface NumberSchema extends Schema { type: 'number', default?: number };
interface BooleanSchema extends Schema { type: 'boolean', default?: boolean };
interface StringSchema extends Schema { type: 'string', default?: string };
interface DateSchema extends Schema { type: 'date', default?: Date };
interface ObjectSchema extends Schema { type: 'object', default?: object };
```

Then the map is:

```
interface ItemSchema {
    [attrName: string]: NumberSchema | BooleanSchema | StringSchema | DateSchema | ObjectSchema;
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Schema%20%7B%20readOnly%3F%3A%20boolean%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20NumberSchema%20extends%20Schema%20%7B%20type%3A%20'number'%2C%20default%3F%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20BooleanSchema%20extends%20Schema%20%7B%20type%3A%20'boolean'%2C%20default%3F%3A%20boolean%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20StringSchema%20extends%20Schema%20%7B%20type%3A%20'string'%2C%20default%3F%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20DateSchema%20extends%20Schema%20%7B%20type%3A%20'date'%2C%20default%3F%3A%20Date%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20ObjectSchema%20extends%20Schema%20%7B%20type%3A%20'object'%2C%20default%3F%3A%20object%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ItemSchema%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BattrName%3A%20string%5D%3A%20NumberSchema%20%7C%20BooleanSchema%20%7C%20StringSchema%20%7C%20DateSchema%20%7C%20ObjectSchema%3B%0D%0A%7D))

Answer (score 0):

I also (still, 6 years later) couldn't find any official documentation, but: **It seems `&` has higher precedence than `|`**.

I just tested it under TS v4.6, using IntelliJ's "Alias for" feature, which shows you a "resolved" version of a type declaration when hovering over the name, and

`type test = {prop1: boolean} & {prop2: string} | {prop3: number}` becomes
`({prop1: boolean} & {prop2: string}) | {prop3: number}` (note the parenthesis).

And to make sure it isn't just a case of "same precedence, resolve left to right":

`type test = {prop1: boolean} | {prop2: string} & {prop3: number}` becomes
`{prop1: boolean} | ({prop2: string} & {prop3: number})`.